# Create Database With File Stream Enabaled

Tags: sql-server, filestream

I am tring to create a database with Filestream option. The purpose to make a filestream database is to store images.I do have Filestream Enabled. And this is the first time I am using FileStream. Here is the script that i am using to create database

```
Create Database AT_DEV  
ON   
PRIMARY (Name = FS1,    
         FILENAME = 'c:\data\AT_DEV.mdf'),  
         FILEGROUP FileSteamGrop1 CONTAINS FILESTREAM   
         (NAME = FS2,  
          FILENAME = 'c:\data\AT_DEV_fileStream1')  
         LOG ON   
         (NAME = FS_Log1,  
          FILENAME = 'c:\data\AT_DEV_LOG.ldf')
```

and I am getting this error.

> Unable to open the physical file
>   "c:\data\AT_DEV_fileStream1".
>   Operating system error -2147024891:
>   "0x80070005(Access is denied.)".

Am I missing something here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to give the SQL Server service account permissions on `c:\data`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this issue, here is the summary:
Operating system XP SP3
Sql Server 2008  R2 Enterprise version.

Microsoft is well aware of this issue and has a hotfix for this issue.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/978835

Just install this hotfix and restart your computer and try to run the script to create database again and it will work.

Hope this will help someone and will not waist as much time i did.

Comment: Your link is for a hotfix "Service cannot access the \?? namespace in Windows XP" sure that is the correct one?

Comment: I think it is. I think he made a typo and the line that reads "Operating System SP SP3" should actually read "Operating System XP SP3" in which case probably that is the intended hotfix.

Comment: @Maverik - Having actually read past the title now I agree! (+1)

Comment: Yes I made a typo, sorry about that.